# API Call for Marvel Developers, Only Receiving One Page

Tags: python-3.x, api

So, the Marvel Developer's website is pretty cool, but some of the "How To" link is down and I recently had to use their API for a project.  My problem is that the API call I was using was only pulling down one page of characters, or 20 characters.  Since the documentation isn't available, is there a general trick to pulling down all the pages?  I should have been getting more like 200 characters.  Example "3-Man to Ultra-Man"  Code I used is below....

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

url = 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=<my_api_key>'
json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)
new_dict = {}

print (data['attributionText'])

for people in data['data']['results']:
    char = (people ['name'])
print(char)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have implemented some paging in their API. See the json response keys in the json `data`:

```
In [41]: j['data'].keys()
Out[41]: dict_keys(['offset', 'limit', 'total', 'count', 'results'])

In [42]: j['data']['offset']
Out[42]: 0

In [43]: j['data']['limit']
Out[43]: 20

In [44]: j['data']['total']
Out[44]: 1491

In [45]: j['data']['count']
Out[45]: 20
```

You can usually control the paging in your request by adding the paging parameters as query params. You can also usually control sorting.

I tried a couple and it seemed to work. So if you change your request to this:

`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=foobar&hash=specialhashasdescribed&limit=100`

You'll get 100 records instead of 20. Usually there are limits to the number of pages you can get in a single request (not sure what it is here). Also, this is only the first page of records. To get the next page of 100, use the offset parameter, which tells the API how many records to skip before returning (it's also sometimes the number of *pages* to skip. But in this case records).

If you make a GET request like this:

`http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=foobar&hash=specialhashasdescribed&limit=100&offset=100`

You'll get the second page of 100 records.

Usually when you're using an API like this, you have to write the code to page through the result set yourself by changing the offset parameter and using some simple arithmetic.

Here's a quick python file to show everything, along with its output. It uses the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, which you can install using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

```
  import os
  import time

  from hashlib import md5

  import requests  # pip install requests to get this library

  # getting this from env variables, you can replace them with your
  # values, but keep the private key private!
  PUBLIC_KEY = os.getenv('MARVEL_PUBLIC_KEY')
  PRIVATE_KEY = os.getenv('MARVEL_PRIVATE_KEY')


  CHARACTER_URL = 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters'


  def get_hash_and_ts_params():
      ts = str(time.time())
      combined = ''.join([ts, PRIVATE_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY])
      hash_value = md5(combined.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
      return {'ts': ts, 'hash': hash_value}


  def paged_requests(page_size=100):
      params = {'apikey': PUBLIC_KEY, 'limit': page_size}
      for i in range(2):
          hash_params = get_hash_and_ts_params()
          params.update(hash_params)
          params.update({'offset': page_size * i}) # offset, how many records to skip
          resp = requests.get(CHARACTER_URL, params)
          print(f'Requested page {i} of {page_size} records')
          resp.raise_for_status()  # stop if there are any errors!
          print(f'Full request URL: {resp.request.url}')
          j = resp.json()
          first_ten = [a['name'] for a in j['data']['results']][:10]
          print(f'First ten records: {first_ten}')
      print('Done')


  if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      paged_requests()
```

And the output it produced on my machine, with my API values:

```
root@7a1440316d88:/# python marvel.py
Requested page 0 of 100 records
Full request URL: http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=my_public_key&limit=100&ts=1&hash=my_unique_has_value_1&offset=0
First ten records: ['3-D Man', 'A-Bomb (HAS)', 'A.I.M.', 'Aaron Stack', 'Abomination (Emil Blonsky)', 'Abomination (Ultimate)', 'Absorbing Man', 'Abyss', 'Abyss (Age of Apocalypse)', 'Adam Destine']
Requested page 1 of 100 records
Full request URL: http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=my_public_key&limit=100&ts=2&hash=my_unique_hash_value_2&offset=100
First ten records: ['Ben Parker', 'Ben Reilly', 'Ben Urich', 'Bengal', 'Beta-Ray Bill', 'Betty Brant', 'Betty Ross', 'Beyonder', 'Bi-Beast', 'Big Bertha']
Done
```